# Navigable UITableView section footers in iOS?

Tags: ios, footer, user-interaction, uitableview

I'd like to implement a "Sign In" form similar to those in already existing apps, for example:

[image: Twitter]
[image: Dropbox]

Screenshots are from Twitter and Dropbox. The "Forgot password?" option is tappable and it navigates to another view. I'd like to make something like that, but I'm not sure if such "Forgot password?" text is the footer of the grouped `UITableView`: I've been searching in the documentation if it is possible to enable user interaction in a footer, but I couldn´t find anything regarding that. Or maybe it is a `UILabel`? How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the method `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`

there you can create a view with a label, button or whatever you need.. Same works for the header with `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Answer (score 0):

Implement the delegate method

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Then create UIButton with "Forgot Password" title, add that as subview to a UIView and return that view as the footer view.